# Cube root using Newton Raphson

Tags: c, floating-point

This is a code that I wrote to find the cube root of a number using Newton Raphson. However, it always shows the answer as -1#IND0. Can you help me find what is wrong with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float x_0,x,x_m,n;
    int m,i=0;
    printf("Enter integer you wish to find the cube root of: ");
    scanf("%f",&n);
    printf("\nEnter your first guess and number of steps: ");
    scanf("%f %d",&x_0,&m);
    x_m=(1/3)*((2*x_0)+(n/(x_0*x_0)));
//  printf("\nx_m=%f\nx_0=%f\nm=%d",x_m,x_0,m);
    while( i<m) 
    {
        x=x_m;
        x_m=(1/3)*((2*x)+(n/(x*x)));
        i++;
    }
    printf("\nThe cube root of %.0f is approximately %.5f",n,x_m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To start with , check for success of `scanf()`

Comment: If you want the user to enter an integer, why do you use floating point values?

Comment: still, it shouldn't affect the answer.

Comment: As for your problem, please learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values, and even perform calculations using the variables. Also, to better be able to debug an application like this, split up the calculations into smaller parts to make sure that each part gives the expected result.

Comment: By the way, `1/3` is an *integer* division. Its result will be zero. You figure out what happens next. Using a debugger you would have found this out within a few seconds.

Comment: `x_m` becomes 0 from the very beginning.

Comment: And please also learn to use a proper, descriptive title for a question. The current title is meaningless.

Comment: The method you use is dangerous, what if the user wants to compute the cube root of 0?

Comment: The sight of essentially the same formula written down twice should trigger your refactoring instinct. Do you really need this repetition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the loop starts, `m_x` will be zero since `(1/3)` is zero (integer division).

On the first iteration, `(n/(x*x))` is then a poll as `x` will be zero. That accounts for the output being `-1#IND0`.

The fix, as always, is to remove all those extra parentheses that folk always seem to put in:

```
x_m=(2*x + n/(x*x))/3;
```

&c. (although your duplication of the Newton Raphson formula is unsatisfactory - as you have to put the fix in two places.). Because `x` is a floating point type, all the arithmetic will be performed in floating point, due to the sensible rules of type promotion.

After you've fixed this, bin it and use `cbrt`, from the C standard library header `math.h`.

Comment: Please also mention a check on `x_0` not being 0.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Why check for this problematic value and not the thousands of other problematic values: `0x1.0p80f`, `0x1.0p-80f`, …?

Answer (score 1):

Before the `while` you have

```
x_m=(1/3)*((2*x_0)+(n/(x_0*x_0)));
```

Since `1/3` will yield `0`, `x_m` will be `0`. And then you have

```
x_m=(1/3)*((2*x)+(n/(x*x)));
```

where you use `x*x` as a quantity to divide `n` with. Since `x` is `0`, the result will have an undefined behavior. Try to make sure the amount you divide with is not 0, but a valid value, start with `(1.0/3)`.